# ingress second-level domain name enters the second-level directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

for example:

```
abc.example.com nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /abc
test1.example.com nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /test1
test2.example.com nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /test2
...
```

How to configure it in ingress? My configuration like this has no effect.

There are many second-level domain names. I don’t want to write them all down one by one.

```yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: online-tools-sub-ingress
  namespace: online-tools-project
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: online-tools
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v1
  annotations:
    kubesphere.io/creator: admin
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: online-tools-core.online-tools-project.svc.cluster.local
spec:
  rules:
    - host: '*.example.com'
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: online-tools-core
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without rewrite target as given below

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: abc-svc
            servicePort: 80
  - host: test1.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: test1-svc
            servicePort: 80
  - host: test2.example.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: test2-svc
            servicePort: 80
```